# repeat macro after error stops execution

Tags: emacs, macros, repeat

My objective is to remove duplicated stanzas in xml files. I am sure I have a duplicated stanza if the first line of the stanza is found multiple times in the file.

I have created a macro that finds the first line of my stanzas through interactive search, then Ctrl-S again to go to the next occurrence. If found, I then mark the section I want to delete and delete it. My macro terminates here.

If my Ctrl-s does not find the next occurrence, my macro stops, which is exacly what I want it to do. However, when I Esc 1000 Ctrl-x e to execute my macro multiple times, when the error is found also the 1000 cycle stops. I am happy for the macro to stop, but I want to execute it again after the error. Is this possible? Or is there already a macro somewhere to remove duplicates stanzas or groups of lines from a file?

My macro:

```
C-s         ;; isearch-forward
<Conduit        ;; self-insert-command * 8
SPC         ;; self-insert-command
6*C-w           ;; kill-region
C-s         ;; isearch-forward
C-a         ;; beginning-of-line
C-SPC           ;; set-mark-command
C-s         ;; isearch-forward
<           ;; self-insert-command
/           ;; nxml-electric-slash
Conduit>        ;; self-insert-command * 8
<right>         ;; forward-char
C-w         ;; kill-region
```

Thanks

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. It would be nice if Emacs provided a convenient interactive way to handle error conditions inside keyboard macros, but I suspect juanleon's answer might be your best bet at present.

A workaround in general is to not use `C-s`, but instead use something like `M-: (search-forward "foo" nil t) RET` to search for "foo" without triggering an error if it's not there. In this example there would be more to it, though.

For one-off processing, what I tend to do in these kinds of situation is generate a buffer of the results I'm interested in, and then process *that* with the keyboard macro.

This example is actually a bit tricky, but you could `occur` all the lines matching the pattern, pipe through `sort | uniq --all-repeated=separate`, and then eliminate the first line of each group. That leaves you with a the exact number of instances you wish to remove for each duplicate, so your keyboard macro could grab a line from that list, find the last instance of it in the original buffer, delete it, and move to the next line in the list.

If this is a common activity, a custom elisp function would seem like the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to achieve is to run a macro repeatedly regardless of errors, this would be a way to do it:

```
(defun repeat-macro-until-abort ()
  (interactive)
  (while t
    (ignore-errors
      (kmacro-call-macro 0))))
```

It will run your last macro until you hit C-g.  Please notice that it won't be stopped even by reaching end-of-buffer.

Answer (score 0):

There is a easy way to remove lines that match a regexp: `M-x flush-lines`

If you know the regexp for the stanza you want to remove, you can type `C-M-% <your-regexp> RET RET` and you witll iterate over the occurences chosing what to remove (type ! for removing every of them).  C-M-% is the default keybinding for `query-replace-regexp`.

Comment: Thanks juanleon. Unfortunately I have to use interactive search as the  lines to remove are always changing in the file. I may have the following: line_abc------line_cdf <other lines not to be removed> line_abc-----line_cdf <otherlines not to be removed> line_rty---line_uip <other lines> line_rty---line_uip and so on, the content of the sections to be removed is always different, I know what to search for to start with, but then I have to check if the rest of the line is duplicated in the file somewhere and remove the duplicate.

Comment: If you post a real example, maybe somebody can help with the regexp you need (if a regexp is a solution, that I don't know for your case, but I know that many times the power of regexes is underestimated)

Comment: My question is quite generic, it concerns removing duplicated groups of lines in a file. There are many such duplicates, and the groups of lines are always different, I don't have to always search for the same lines, I have to find "some" lines, then find if there are more instances of these lines, remove the duplicates, then start the cycle again by finding the next set of lines (different from before). It all boils down to: can a repeated macro be restarted (not resumed from the error, but restarted from the beginning) after an error? Perhaps it is possible in lisp, but I am no lisp expert.

Comment: If this is really what you want, see my other answer.